# How to delete all cookies and form data when page loads in js?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to delete all the cookies and form datas when the page loads.

I have tried this one..

```
$.cookie('my_cookie_name', null);
```

Here, `my_cookie_name` is set to null i.e using the particular cookie name, the value is set to null. But, I need to delete all the cookies as well as form data when the page loads.

Is it possible using javascript or jquery?

Comment: for clearing form data?

Comment: document.cookie = name + "=;expires=Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 GMT";  what it means? the year

Comment: When you set a past date as expire of cookies its deleted. for you `for (var it in $.cookie()) $.removeCookie(it);` is best as you are using [jquery.cookie](http://plugins.jquery.com/cookie/) plugin